# How to reduce size of complex svg for web?

Tags: html, svg, html5-canvas

I'm currently working with some complex illustrations and wants to use them as .svg on my website. I tried using .svgz files but they are not working properly when deployed on sever. Is there anyway I can reduce the size of .svg files. My current .svg size is going upto 2.5 -  3 mb which I don't want. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: https://compressor.io/ - Give it a try

Comment: If you had typed "svgz" into the search box of this site.  The first result has an explanation of how to get svgz files working on your server. See: http://kaioa.com/node/45

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For solve problem you need prepare you svg. I use Illustrator. Before save you need:

1. Ungroup all elements
2. Expand (Fill, stroke, other options) - convert
   to pure curves
3. Don't use gradients and blur if it possible
4. Use svgo compression tool

This steps allow me usual minify size on 10-50%, depends of image.